# What are the arguments for define-globalized-minor-mode in Emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

I want a non-global minor mode to be enabled on the Emacs start up. I found it can be done with that code:

```
(define-globalized-minor-mode my-global-mode
  the-mode
  (lambda ()
    (the-mode t))
)
(my-global-mode t)
```

But I don't get it. What do two last arguments of the `define-globalized-minor-mode` do? `the-mode` and a `lambda`. More precisely why do I need both, isn't it tautology?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A globalized minor mode is a global minor mode that is created from an existing (non-global) minor mode.  Nothing more.

The first arg to `define-globalized-minor-mode` is the name (a symbol) of the global minor mode you want to create.  The second arg is the existing (non-global) minor mode function (a symbol) that you want to use to create the global one.

The third arg is a function that turns the minor mode on.  The minor mode function typically is a toggle command.  Invoking it interactively with no args does *not* turn the mode on. (Invoking it from Lisp with no args *does* turn it on.)

And some minor modes have a defined (named) separate command to turn them on.  E.g., `turn-on-visual-line-mode` is a separate command from `visual-line-mode`.  It is equivalent to `(lambda () visual-line-mode 1))`.  So you could pass as the third arg either the symbol `turn-on-visual-line-mode`or the equivalent lambda form.

That's really all there is to it.

Comment: If there are modes with which command `visual-line-mode 1` whouldn't work then it does make sense. I thought it would work with any one.

Comment: No, that's not the point. Argument `TURN-ON` is not optional, because a function is needed that ***needs no argument*** and turns the mode on.  The mode function itself needs an argument to turn the mode on.  Think of the `TURN-ON` function being called on a normal hook, for instance.

Comment: Isn't it a flaw in the architecture then? Is it possible to wrap this in something? So that I could call `(globalize the-mode)` instead of this huge and repetitive code.

Comment: If you think so, try passing your suggestion to its designers and developers: `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: @Drew Hi Drew, the definition of `define-minor-mode` has changed such that the minor-mode functions without args turn the mode on. I think this is worth an edit of this answer.

Comment: @Tobias: Done. Please check whether the edit does what you suggest.